# Fixing Laravel encoding in MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, mamp, mamp-pro

I'm using laravel 4.

During a migration I'm inserting rows into a table I created.

Example:

```
        Schema::create('month', function(Blueprint $table)
                {
                        $table->integer('id');

                        $table->string('name');

                });

           DB::table('month')->insert(
                    array(
                            array(
                                    'id' => 1,
                                    'name' => 'Janeiro'
                            ),
                            array(
                                    'id' => 2,
                                    'name' => 'Fevereiro'
                            ),
                            array(
                                    'id' => 3,
                                    'name' => 'Março'
                            ),
                            array(
                                    'id' => 4,
                                    'name' => 'Abril'
                            ),
                            array(
                                    'id' => 5,
                                    'name' => 'Maio'
                            ),
                            array(
                                    'id' => 2,
                                    'name' => 'Junho'
                            ),                                
                            array(
                                    'id' => 7,
                                    'name' => 'Julho'
                            ),
                            array(
                                    'id' => 8,
                                    'name' => 'Agosto'
                            ),
                            array(
                                    'id' => 9,
                                    'name' => 'Setembro'
                            ),
                            array(
                                    'id' => 10,
                                    'name' => 'Outubro'
                            ),
                            array(
                                    'id' => 11,
                                    'name' => 'Novembro'
                            ),
                            array(
                                    'id' => 12,
                                    'name' => 'Dezembro'
                            ),                                   

                    ));
```

The problem is that month 3,Março is inserted as "Mar" and not as "Março" as it should.

My Laravel Database config is correct I think:

```
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'localhost',
        'database'  => 'alaviagens',
        'username'  => 'alaviagens',
        'password'  => '',
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
```

The table is charset is also correct i think:

```
    CREATE TABLE `month` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

If I change the record itself in the database using for example Sequel Pro I can change it successfully to "Março".

Any idea what might be causing this and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your Laravel config and database/table collation seem fine, you have to make sure that your migration/seed php files are saved in utf8 encoding.

Ofcourse it's obvious that your database connection should also be running in utf8. Laravel should [provide that by default](https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php#L29), but if for any reason it's not done you should fix it by enforcing utf8 in mysql server config.

```
//file /etc/mysql/my.cnf

[mysqld]
...
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
...
```

### **EDIT:**

As you are using standard **MAMP** on OSX follow the below instruction on how to change mysql settings.

1) Check the location of loaded my.cnf configs, run in terminal:

`mysql --help | grep cnf`

For MAMP 2.0 it should result in something similar to

`/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /Applications/MAMP/conf/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf`

2) Create `my.cnf` in one of the file paths above and modify as per my initial instruction.

If you are using **MAMP PRO**, go under the `File > Edit Template > MySQL my.cnf` to make the changes.

### **EDIT 2:**

If you have problems with my.cnf, you can also use some predefined templates, shipped with MAMP

a) check the templates' locations

```
cd /Applications/MAMP/
find . | grep cnf
```

that will result in

```
./Library/support-files/my-huge.cnf
./Library/support-files/my-innodb-heavy-4G.cnf
./Library/support-files/my-large.cnf
./Library/support-files/my-medium.cnf
./Library/support-files/my-small.cnf
```

so now you can pick one of the above templates and copy it to MAMP directory and modify it easily:

```
sudo cp /Applications/MAMP/Library/share/mysql/my-medium.cnf /Applications/MAMP/Library/my.cnf
```

### **FINAL STEP:**

#### RESTART MAMP/MYSQL

Comment: I's using MAMP in MAC OS X, I actually tried creating the my.cnf file with that configuration (I read that some where in google, because MAMP does not generate a my.cnf file) but it didn t work.

Comment: @ciTiger check my edit, I included a lot of additional info on MAMP